# Same query executed on the same program with different SQLite providers has an huge different execution time

Tags: c#, sqlite

So, I'm migrating a C# application from framework (3.5) (Visual Studio 2008) to framework (4.5.1) (Visual Studio 2013). We are using SQLite database and upgraded the entity framework to 6.1.3 and SQLite references to the ultimate (1.0.98).
After some predicted problems solved and others not so predicted, I got stuck at this one.
I have a query executed at code side that has different execution times between the two frameworks and unfortunately, the new one has worst results.
At the old one (3.5) the execution time it's about 2-3 secs and in the new one it's almost 2 minutes. I guarantee that the DB is the same and always have the same data volume.

There's another thing...If I execute the query directly on the SQLite, the execution time it's like on the framework 4.5.1 (almost 2 minutes). How is it possible that it takes more time on SQLite than on the old app?

I create two dummy projects (one for each framework) to ensure that it is nothing that I lost on the migration but the results still the same.

It's definitely something with the old framework. My theory is that some DB parameter has being sent on the old app that turns the query more efficient but I can't find which one.

To run the query I'm using the following commad:

SQLiteCommand.Execute(query, SQLiteExecuteType.NonQuery, "MyConnectionString", new object[] { });

(the same on the two apps)

This is the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output from the **SQLITE DATABASE (v3.5.85.2505):**

```
selectid    order   from    detail
1   0   0   SCAN TABLE SI_REFERENCES USING INDEX IDX_SI_REFERENCES_FKEY
1   0   0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0   0   0   SCAN TABLE SI_INVOICE
0   1   1   SEARCH TABLE HEADER USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0   2   2   SEARCH TABLE CUSTOMER USING INDEX IDX_CUSTOMER_HEADERID (HEADERID=?)
0   3   3   SEARCH TABLE SI_LINE USING INDEX IDX_SI_LINE_3 (FKEY=?)
0   4   4   SEARCH SUBQUERY 1 AS T1 USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (HEADERID=? AND FKEY=?)
0   0   0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
0   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 3
```

This is the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output from the **NEW PROGRAM (4.5.1) SQLITE(1.0.98):**

```
selectid    order   from    detail
1 0 0 SCAN TABLE SI_REFERENCES USING INDEX IDX_SI_REFERENCES_FKEY
1 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0 0 0 SCAN TABLE SI_INVOICE
0 1 1 SEARCH TABLE HEADER USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0 2 2 SEARCH TABLE CUSTOMER USING INDEX IDX_CUSTOMER_HEADERID (HEADERID=?)
0 3 3 SEARCH TABLE SI_LINE USING INDEX IDX_SI_LINE_3 (FKEY=?)
0 4 4 SEARCH SUBQUERY 1 AS T1 USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (HEADERID=? AND FKE
Y=?)
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0 0 0 EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
0 0 0 EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 3
```

This is the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output from the **OLD PROGRAM (3.5) SQLITE (1.0.88):**

```
selectid    order   from    detail
1 0 0 SCAN TABLE SI_REFERENCES (~1000000 rows)
1 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0 0 0 SCAN TABLE SI_INVOICE (~250000 rows)
0 1 1 SEARCH TABLE HEADER USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0 2 2 SEARCH TABLE CUSTOMER USING INDEX IDX_CUSTOMER_1 (CUSTOMERID=?) (~2 rows)

0 3 3 SEARCH TABLE SI_LINE USING INDEX IDX_SI_LINE_3 (FKEY=?) (~2 rows)
0 4 4 SEARCH SUBQUERY 1 AS T1 USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (HEADERID=? AND FKE
Y=?) (~3 rows)
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0 0 0 EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
0 0 0 EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 3
```

Hope someone can help!

Best Regards

Comment: Forgot to mention that the program with the framework 3.5 has the 1.0.88 SQLite references and the program with the framework 4.5.1 has the ultimate 1.0.98.

Comment: Show the relevant parts of the database schema, the query, and the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output with both SQLite versions.

Comment: I just edit the answer to include the query and the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output, but that is only one version of SQLite database. The only thing that changes is the ADO.NET provider for SQLite. I remind that in the old version we are using the 1.0.88 and at the new one we use the 1.0.98.

Comment: The SQLite library is compiled into the ADO.NET provider. It's exactly this difference that you're seeing.

Comment: Right. But isn't it strange that the execution time got a lot worst?? And there's nothing I can do to improve the query performance without remaking the query? If it was just this one that wouldn't be a problem but this is a long and a little bit complex application with a lot of similar problems...
And undo to the old version is not an option...

Comment: I'm still waiting for the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output of the other version.

Comment: These three outputs look as if they were from the same database engine. (What matters is the database library actually used, not the database file.)

Comment: You're right CL. But those 2 output's are with different libraries. The new program uses the System.Data.SQLite v1.0.98.0 and the old one (and fastest) uses the System.Data.SQLite v1.0.88.0...I copied the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output from these two different libraries versions. 
I also tried with the Devart provider but the results are almost the same as the new SQLite library version.

Comment: I dumped the results to the debugging console...just to reinforce the idea that are different libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some differences in how the query planner tries to execute your queries.
In the new version, it uses an index to read the `SI_REFERENCES` table instead of scanning it (because that would remove on step from the GROUP BY processing), and it uses a different index for looking up rows from the `CUSTOMER` table.

The SQLite documentation has a [checklist for fixing query planner problems](http://sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html#howtofix).
In pretty much all cases, running [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) should help (and would also have been useful in the old version).
Only as a last resort, you can try to force it to execute the query like in the old version by adding INDEXED BY clauses (`... FROM SI_REFERENCES NOT INDEXED GROUP BY ...`, `... JOIN CUSTOMER INDEXED BY IDX_CUSTOMER_1 ON ...`).

Comment: Thanks a lot CL. Running Analyze resolve all my problems...I can't believe how come no one here remembered this before.
Thanks again!